# Как правильно организовать структуру JS кода

Tags: javascript, функции

я начал делать игру - "Дурак" на JS, и в процессе написания столкнулся с "хаосом" в коде. У меня есть несколько вопросов:

1 - Стоит ли выносить некоторые функции в отдельные файлы? Я обнаружил что у меня очень много функций, если бы это был просто сайт, я бы разбивал код по модулям, типа - слайдер, аккордеон, и т.д. Но здесь все функции относятся к одной логике - игре.

2 - Как правильно делать структуру кода?  К примеру я вынес наверх функции отвечающие за -"мелкую" дублирующуюся логику - отфильтровать массив, отсортировать, перетасовать, найти рандомное число и т.д.

3 - И где лучше вызывать функции? в конце после всех функций, или сразу после каждой функции.

4 - Стоит ли строить цепочку из функций? К примеру у меня есть функция которая определяет козырную карту, я могу в конце этой функции запустить функцию отвечающую за раздачу карт, или же её стоит запускать сразу после функции которая определяет козырную карту?

Comment: Хороший ответ на такой вопрос будет состоять из пары-тройки книг.. и пары лет набора опыта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> я начал делать игру - "Дурак" на JS

Показалось что дурак без кавычек и дефис после. (чуточку юмора)

> 1 - Стоит ли выносить некоторые функции в отдельные файлы? Я обнаружил что у меня очень много функций, если бы это был просто сайт, я бы разбивал код по модулям, типа - слайдер, аккордеон, и т.д. Но здесь все функции относятся к одной логике - игре.

Конечно, стоит если много функций - еслиб побольше деталей, можно было бы поподробнее. Можете разбить вопрос на несколько чтоб получить развернутый ответ по пунктам.

> 2 - Как правильно делать структуру кода? К примеру я вынес наверх функции отвечающие за -"мелкую" дублирующуюся логику - отфильтровать массив, отсортировать, перетасовать, найти рандомное число и т.д.

Что значит наверх? Если структуру проекта то можно посмотреть рекомендации [тут](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html) рекомендации конечно по реакт но принцип у всех тотже - компонентный подход (принцип разделяй и властвуй).

> 3 - И где лучше вызывать функции? в конце после всех функций, или сразу после каждой функции.

Сразу после каждой, звучит немного дико. Функции вызываются после определения, где есть в этом необходимость по логике.

> 4 - Стоит ли строить цепочку из функций? К примеру у меня есть функция которая определяет козырную карту, я могу в конце этой функции запустить функцию отвечающую за раздачу карт, или же её стоит запускать сразу после функции которая определяет козырную карту?

Исходя из *приципа единственной ответственности* я бы сказал что не стоит. Но опять если у вас это основной метод "New Game" и ему нужно всё это, то это не цепочка, а последовательный вызов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я как-раз таки, грубо говоря, пришел из React. Там я делал бы хуки, отдельные компоненты, и т.д, вызывал бы их в useEffect и так далее... Но решил написать игру на чистом JS, для практики.

Comment: Я имел ввиду наверх самого файла, как переменные